# How to use Magento 1.9.2.3 REST or SOAP API to get list of products - working example required

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api

I'm a new to Magento API.
Tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40734545/how-to-get-product-info-using-rest-api-in-magento
but all I'm getting is a blank page.
Can anyone help or advice what should I do ?

Edited:

In the meantime I worked on it a bit and found that to make it work oauth php extension is required (so installed it).
Now I 'm getting a login screen which is a promising sign :)

SOAP is working fine.
Need REST example.

Comment: Did you solve your issue? How did you install oAuth in server? @ Rob D. A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you referenced was straight from the [horse's mouth](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html), so it should work. Everything else is environment related.

Enable [php error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) printing to find out the cause of your blank page. My guess is that you may just have something like "OAuth" php module not installed on your server.
If that does not work, always use xDebug (or another one that let's you walk line by line in your code) to debug your code. If you are serious about php development at all, this is the first thing you will configure after you install your server. Do not waste your time working without a debugger.

Comment: Thanks mate, I did, and finally I managed to make it work. For now can only read data but soon will check add/update procedures.